# What is the manually typed equivalent of resources in rails routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Suppose `rails new myapp && cd myapp && rails g scaffold Teacher`

`routes.rb` contains `resources :teachers`

What is the manually typed equivalent of this single line in `routes.rb`? (the reason I ask is because I would like to keep most, but edit some of the routes)

Comment: The routes show up in `rails routes`. I think you can derive the "manual" code from that output

Comment: "but edit some of the routes" - that's interesting. What, how and why do you want to edit? I mean, if you want to step away from the convention, you should have a good reason.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am creating a very basic API. I do not want to allow anything unnecessary. The only two things a user could need is to view some data ('get') or delete a record ('destroy') or insert a new record ('create')

Comment: So no editing any routes? Just not using some actions? And that's three things, not two :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I guess so. I also wasn't sure if `resources` provided other kinds of routes, hence, want to only include the ones that could ever be necessary. I should also mention I want to manually adjust the routes (to include a key to authenticate users and their permissions), hence why I want to see what resources means manually

Comment: Adding authentication key to the URL path is a terrible, terrible idea. Don't do that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev amazon do it for their S3 buckets. i think it is very convenient for users, whilst maintains the admin's ability to cancel an account if necessary (i.e. just delete the private key from a database of keys). I'm after the code that would go in `routes.rb` that would provide exactly the same functionality as `resources :teachers`. Don't get me wrong, I am very appreciative of your advice as it is the rails way, but I want to deviate here for the sake learning and examining exactly what `resources :teachers` means

Comment: "amazon do it for their S3 buckets" - do they, though? Can you point me to an example? AFAIK, amazon expects auth info as query params (or request headers/body, where appropriate). As this does not affect routing, you don't need to change routes to do the same.

Comment: "I'm after the code that would go in routes.rb that would provide exactly the same functionality as resources :teachers" - my answer and the hint about `rails routes` are not enough? It's not a complete solution, yes, but the missing code should be almost trivial to extrapolate. This will be useful: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The only two things a user could need is to view some data ('get') or delete a record ('destroy') or insert a new record ('create')

This scenario is supported:

```
 resources :teachers, only: [:show, :destroy, :create]
```

As for the "manual" routes, you could express, say, the `:show` route like this:

```
 get '/teachers/:id', to: 'teachers#show'
```

The full equivalents are as follows:

```rb
get '/teachers' => 'teachers#index'
get '/teachers/:id' => 'teachers#show'
get '/teachers/new' => 'teachers#new'
post '/teachers' => 'teachers#create'
get '/teachers/:id/edit' => 'teachers#edit'
put '/teachers/:id' => 'teachers#update'
delete '/teachers/:id' => 'teachers#destroy'
```